# Keyboard leave a blank space after saving

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield

Since the new Swift version, it looks like the keyboard leaves a blank space when I save the data.

MyView

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddUpdateUrl: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @EnvironmentObject var controller: PlacesViewController
    
    @Binding var place: Place
    @State var url = ""
    
    var updateMode = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Website")
                .font(.callout)
            TextField("", text: $url)
                .keyboardType(.URL)
                .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: 1)
        }
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing: Button(action: {save()}) {Text("Save")}.disabled(url.isEmpty)
        )
        .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
    }
    
    private func save() {
        if !url.isEmpty {
            place.url = url
            if updateMode {
                controller.update(place: place)
            }
        }
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
}
```

And the result.
The view before trying to update the website
[image: The view before trying to update the Webiste]

The view to add the website
[image: The view to add the webiste]

After clicking the save button
[image: After clicking the save button]

I have the same behavior on the simulator and on my iPhone 11 (ios 14.3)

The *.resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()* is an extension that removes the keyboard.

```
    struct ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture: ViewModifier {
    var gesture = DragGesture().onChanged {_ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.gesture(gesture)
    }
}

extension View {
    func resignKeyboardOnDragGesture() -> some View {
        return modifier(ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture())
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `.resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()`?

Comment: It's an extension that removes the keyboard. (I place the code in the original post).

Comment: Did you ever work out what was causing this?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is very late but if you still have this issues.

Add the following to your view:

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
```

This should no longer happen.